# What causes the "Warning: GearmanClient::runTasks(): Could not call the function in ..." message?

Tags: exception, callback, gearman

I started to use Gearman for running tasks through several workers. I get the following message:

Warning: GearmanClient::runTasks(): Could not call the function in ....php on line 192.

The line number 192 contains this:
    class Client extends \GearmanClient {
        //...
        $this->setCompleteCallback(...);
        $this->addTast(...);
        //...
        $this->addTast(...);
        $this->runTasks(); // this is line #192
        //...
    }

What can be the reason for this message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some investigation it turned out that the callback function that is called when the worker finishes his task, well, it causes the problem.

If there is an exception thrown from the callback function then it causes the above message.

The solution was to change the callback function, that was to collect the results of each worker. Now, instead of throwing an exception, it stores the problem's description in the list of the results.